# Spherical roots, restricted roots, and the dual group of a symmetric variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reductive-groups, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces, spherical-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and $G$ a semisimple simply-connected group over $k$. Consider a symmetric variety of the form $X=G/H$, for $H=G^\theta$ the fixed point subgroup of an involution $\theta \in \mathrm{Aut}_2(G)$.

There are several root systems that can be attached to the symmetric variety $X$.

1. The restricted roots. These are the roots of the form $\tfrac{1}{2}(\alpha-\alpha^\theta)$, for $\alpha$ the roots of $G$. (Here $\alpha^\theta$ denotes the image of $\alpha$ under the natural action of $\theta$ on the roots. I will denote this root system by $\Phi_\theta$ (and the corresponding simple roots by $\Delta_\theta$). This root system is not reduced in general, but one can take the "shortest" elements to make it reduced.
2. The spherical root system. Following Sakellaridis-Venkatesh (Section 2.1), the spherical root system of $X$ is spanned by the generators of the intersections of the extremal rays of the dual cone to the valuation cone of $X$ with the weight lattice of $X$. Sakellaridis and Venkatesh denote this set of simple roots by $\Sigma_X$.
3. Sakellaridis and Venkatesh further construct from $\Sigma_X$ another system of simple roots, that they denote by $\Delta_X$, and write $\Phi_X$ for the corresponding root system. I think this is what is called the "minimal root system" in Timashev's book, and the one originally considered by Brion and later generalized by Knop.

Conjecturally (from Knop-Schalke), the Gaitsgory-Nadler dual group $G^\vee_X$ of the variety $X$ is a reductive group with root system $\Phi_X^\vee$, the dual of $\Phi_X$. According to Gaitsgory-Nadler, since $X$ is a symmetric variety, $G^\vee_X$ coincides with the dual group $\check{H}_\theta$ associated to the real form $G_\mathbb{R}$ of $G$ corresponding to $\theta$.

**I am confused about these root systems, when they are equal and when they differ, and how do they differ.** In particular, I am trying to understand some simple examples, where the computations should be quite explicit.

I would like to understand the example where $G=\mathrm{SL}_n$, for $n=2m$ and $\theta$ is the inner involution given by conjugation by the diagonal matrix with $m$ $1$'s and $m$ $-1$'s. This involution is quasi-split, so the Levi subgroup appearing in Nadler's paper should be the entire Langlands dual group $G^\vee=\mathrm{PSL}_n$.  The restricted root system $\Phi_\theta$ associated to this $\theta$ is a reduced root system of type $C_m$, and thus its Langlands dual is $B_m$. However, in Nadler's table, the dual group of this $G/G^\theta$ is precisely of type $C_m$, so $\Phi_\theta$ cannot be isomorphic to the minimal root system $\Phi_X$ yielding the dual group (in fact it is its dual). **How can I obtain the system $\Phi_X$ in this case?**

Comment: For primitive homogeneous affine spherical varieties, the information of the spherical roots can be read from the tables from the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410472.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might already have found an answer, but hopefully this helps.

The way I think about this is that there are always (at least) three normalizations of the roots to a spherical variety $X$. Some quick notation: let $A\subset B$ be a maximal torus and Borel subgroup of $G$. Let $X=G/H$ be our homogeneous spherical variety, with the following two lattices: $\mathfrak{X}\subset X^\ast(A)$ is the lattice of characters arising from $B$-semi-invariant functions and $\Lambda_X$ is the ``root lattice'' of $X$. This is the sublattice of $\mathfrak{X}$ such that $\mathfrak{X}/\Lambda_X$ is the character group of the automorphism group $Aut^G(X)$.

1. The minimal roots $\Delta_{X}$, which is defined by taking ray generators of the dual cone in $\mathfrak{X}$ to the cone of invariant valuations.
2. The normalized roots $\Delta_X^n$: this set of roots is a set of additive generators of the root lattice $\Lambda_X$ and is crucial to the calculation of $Aut^G(X)$ due to Losev.
3. The Sakellaridis-Venkatesh renormalized roots $\Delta_X^{SV}$: I think this is what you refer to in (2) of your question, which isn't quite stated correctly. What they do is take $\Delta_X$ and renormalize through elements of the root lattice of the group $G$. Sometimes this requires scaling a spherical root by $1/2$ (such as $SL_2/N$) and sometime by $2$ (such as $Spin_6/Spin_5$). The point is now the spherical roots of $X$ lie in the root lattice of $G$. By Knop--Schalke, this is the root system that $\check{G}_X$ is dual to.

Now the point is that when $X=G/G^\theta$ is symmetric, the restricted roots $\Delta_\theta$ is exactly (up to the scale by $1/2$ which is not really necessary) the set of normalized roots $\Delta_X^n$. Namely if you instead set
of elements $\alpha-\theta(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in\Delta,$ then you recover the normalized roots as a subset of the character lattice of $A$. This is explained in Knop's ``Automorphisms, root systems, and compactifications of homogeneous varieties'' paper, and also in Timashev's book.

Calculationally, we can start by calculating $\Delta_X^n=\Delta_\theta$ as above (though you need to make sure that $A$ is in the correct relative position with $\theta$: it needs to be a maximally $\theta$-split maximal torus). Now we can recover $\Delta_X$ by locating which normalized roots are twice a ``distinguished root'' and rescaling it with $1/2$: this has to do with locating which roots in $\Delta_X^n$ which can be halved without violating Luna's axioms. For example, in the example you give with $G=SL_{2m}$ and $X=SL_{2m}/S(GL_m\times GL_m)$, if we use the standard numbering of the roots, then
$$\Delta_X^n = \{\alpha_1+\alpha_{2m-1},\ldots, \alpha_{m-1}+\alpha_{m+1}, 2\alpha_m\}$$
is of Cartan type $C_m$ while
$$\Delta_X = \{\alpha_1+\alpha_{2m-1},\ldots, \alpha_{m-1}+\alpha_{m+1}, \alpha_m\}$$
is type $B_m$. Here the root $\alpha_m$ is distinguished in the sense of Losev. In this case $\Delta_X=\Delta_X^{SV}$, so $\check{G}_X=Sp_{2m}$.

In general, computing $\Delta_X^{SV}$ from $\Delta_X$ requires further scaling if there are spherical roots of the form $2\alpha$ which are not distinguished (replacing $SL_{2m}/S(GL_m\times GL_m)$ with the (disconnected) normalizer of the Levi is an example of this) as well as sometimes scaling a sum $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$ by $2$. This ensures the existence of a morphism $\check{G}_X\to \check{G}$, but means that this map will not be injective in general.

Comment: Hi Leslie, I am a little confused, I think the set of spherical roots are $$\{ \alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2m-1},\cdots,\alpha_{m-1}+\alpha_{m+1},2\alpha_{m} \}$$ from the diagram 5 in page 13 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410472.pdf.

Comment: Ah! Good catch. Thank you. Yeah, the statement that $A$ needs to be in the correct relative position means that either $\theta(\alpha)=\alpha$ or $\theta(\alpha)<0$, so your sign is correct.

Answer (score 7):

There is a small survey published in an [Oberwolfach report](https://publications.mfo.de/handle/mfo/3355) by Bart Van Steirteghem comparing the different normalizations of spherical roots in more detail. The standard normalization is obtained by decreeing spherical roots to be primitive in the *weight lattice of the spherical variety of $X$*. On the other hand, Sakellaridis and Venkatesh want spherical roots to be primitive in the *root lattice of $G$*. As opposed to the standard normalization this leads to a dual group of $X$ which maps to the dual group of $G$. On the other hand, SV-spherical roots are in general not weights of $X$. A third difference is that the SV-root system is invariant under finite maps $X\to X'$ while the standard root system is not.